# JavaScript bitwise & operator appends 1 on unintended position

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

When I run `0x00000000C17E000F & 0x00000000C17E0000` on javascript, it returns `-1048707072` instead of `3246260224`.

Binary of each is

- `0x00000000C17E000F` : (32 **zeros** omitted) 1100 0001 0111 1110 0000 0000 0000 1111
- `0x00000000C17E0000` : (32 **zeros** omitted) 1100 0001 0111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000

so I expected the result of `0x00000000C17E000F & 0x00000000C17E0000` as `3246260224`, but it results in `-1048707072`.

- `3246260224` : (32 of **0** omitted) 1100 0001 0111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
- `-1048707072` : (32 of **1** omitted) 1100 0001 0111 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000

Why does Javascript calculates `0 & 0` as `1` at there (in 33 to 64th bit)?

(I heard that Javascript Number consists of 64bit.)

Comment: `0 & 0` gives me `0` in node and safari

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yeah, `0&0` gives me `0` too, but `0&0` calculation of 33-64th bit was calculated as `1` in that case!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the MDN on bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND):

> The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded.

Your numbers aren't between -2 ^ 31 and 2 ^ 31 so they're changed by the conversion.

Note that this isn't really overflowing nor a limitation of the storage: Numbers in Javascript are 64 bits (IEEE754 doubles) which means they can store all integers between - 2 ^53 and 2 ^53. The limitation at 32 bits  is just with the bitwise operators, by design.

A consequence of this remark is that you may very well design your own functions to do bitwise operations on bigger integers:

```
function and(a, b){
    let abits = Array.from(a.toString(2));
    let bbits = Array.from(b.toString(2));
    return parseInt(abits.map((abit, i)=>abit & bbits[i]).join(""), 2);
}
console.log(and(0x00000000C17E000F, 0x00000000C17E0000)); // 3246260224
```